# errror occured in google api login

Tags: php, google-api

Any ideas how to handle the next error?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: D:\xampp\htdocs>ca-bundle.crt CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in D:\xampp\htdocs\social_login\GoogleLogin\GoogleAPI\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:187 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\social_login\GoogleLogin\GoogleAPI\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 D:\xampp\htdocs\social_login\GoogleLogin\GoogleAPI\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2 D:\xampp\htdocs\social_login\GoogleLogin\GoogleAPI\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(G in D:\xampp\htdocs\social_login\GoogleLogin\GoogleAPI\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code that you're using to do the API login.

Answer (score 0):

Have you uncommented and added a value to the following line in your `php.ini`?

```
;openssl.cafile=
```

Make sure that these two options are specified and point to an up to date certificate bundle.

---

A concrete way to fix this is:

1. Download a cafile [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
2. Save it in your `D:\xampp\` folder and call it `cacert.pem`.
3. Change the relevant line in your `php.ini` to:
   `openssl.cafile=d:\xampp\cacert.pem`.